# ¿Puedo simular el uso de la tecla "print screen"?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

Quisiera saber si puedo simular el uso de la tecla de print screen (la que presionamos para tomar capturas de pantalla) con el navegador, ya sea con JavaScript o PHP.

Ya he utilizado el plugin html2canvas, pero la captura de pantalla se distorsiona. Éste es el script que utilicé:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/html2canvas/0.4.1/html2canvas.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
html2canvas(document.contenido_global, {
    onrendered (canvas) {
        var link = document.getElementById('download');
        var image = canvas.toDataURL();
        link.href = image;
        link.download = 'screenshot.png';
    }
});
</script>
```

Comment: Debe de ser posible programar un script que realice eso, pero quiza este plugin haga algo como lo que necesitas http://html2canvas.hertzen.com/

Comment: Ya he utilizado ese plugin pero la captura de pantalla se distorciona, aquí el script:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depende de lo que quieras decir con que la imagen se distorsiona.

Primero, si tu contenedor contiene imágenes externas, debes pasarle a HTML2Canvas la opción `useCors : true`. En algunos casos, si la imagen está alojada en un servidor que tiene un `Allow Origin` restrictivo, HTML2Canvas no podrá cargarla.

Segundo, si tu contenedor contiene elementos SVG, es muy posible que HTML2Canvas los renderee mal, porque el CSS aplicado a un SVG no es completamente estandar y HTML2Canvas tiende a distorsionar el espesor de las líneas (por ejemplo) y el tamaño de las tipografías. Para esos casos, tienes que añadirle estilos inline a los elementos `text` y `path` (en el caso de gráficos generados con C3).

El ejemplo siguiente sí funciona, pero no estoy usando elementos SVG.

```js
html2canvas(document.getElementById('contenido_global'), {
    useCORS: true,
    onrendered (canvas) {
        var link = document.getElementById('download');
        var image = canvas.toDataURL();
        link.href = image;
        link.download = 'screenshot.png';
    }
});
```

```css
#contenido_global {
background:white;
border:2px solid red;
padding:3px;
margin:3px auto;
width:330px;

}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/html2canvas/0.4.1/html2canvas.min.js"></script>

<a id="download">Descargar</a>

<div id="contenido_global">

Hola Soy el contenido global
<br>
<img src="http://1.bp.blogspot.com/-TIPXtgKPnKA/T2wQ1vkrhII/AAAAAAAAGJs/TKfNJT4MIbM/s320/Cat-01.jpg">
</div>
```